# Why `MediaElements` remains in the memory even after closing the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

See my code please :

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {   
         WrapPanel wp=new WrapPanel ();
         this.Content = wp;
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
              MediaElement video = new MediaElement(); video.Width = video.Height = 200;
              video.Source = new Uri("E:\\testVideo.avi");
              wp.Children.Add(video);
         }
     }
```

It takes a few seconds to display the videos when this code start.
At this time, If you close the program, all videos remains in the memory. (can even hear their voices)

Q: 1- why?

Q: 2- How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your application is still running even though the main window is closed. Since the MediaElements are still initializing and playing it is probably keeping your application open. In order to kill your application when the main window is closed, listen the `Window.Closed` event and shutdown the application by calling:

```
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Thank you . But had no effect.